# How to change desktop's right-click options 

Tags: 11.04, nautilus, menu

Again, I'm running natty in classic mode.

When I right click on the desktop, I get a practically useless menu that goes like

Create Folder
Create Launcher
Organize Desktop by name...

I would like to edit this menu. Note: nautilus-open-terminal is insufficient for my needs because I want to open xterms up.

Comment: @Rinzwind let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/586/discussion-between-owen-maresh-and-rinzwind)

Answer (score 5):

We are unable to remove the default menu entries in Nautilus. However by using [Nautilus Scripts](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Nautilus_Scripts) we may add any script located in `~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts/` to the right click context menu:

[image]